# Calculation in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my code which is not working properly. I need only one record inserted for an employee but it inserts multiple

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (ID VARCHAR(5), formula VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE #table2 (employeid VARCHAR(5), payhead VARCHAR(5), amount MONEY)
CREATE TABLE #table3 (employeid VARCHAR(5), payiD VARCHAR(5), amount MONEY)

INSERT INTO #Table1 
VALUES ('PAY1', NULL), ('PAY2', '(PAY1*12%)'), ('PAY3', 'PAY1 + PAY2')

INSERT INTO #Table2 
VALUES ('E001','PAY1', 2000),('E002','PAY1', 5000),('E003','PAY1', 3000)

INSERT INTO #Table2 
VALUES ('E001','PAY3', 1000),('E002','PAY3', 3000),('E003','PAY3', 2000)

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR (MAX) = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ' + ID + ' = ' + REPLACE(formula,'%','/100') + '
)
AS ' + ID + '
'
FROM #Table1
WHERE formula IS NOT NULL

SET @SQL = ';WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT employeid, Amount as Pay1 
    FROM #table2 
    WHERE EMPLOYEID = ''E001''
)
SELECT * 
INTO #TMP -- insert the result into a new temp table
FROM
    cte ' + @SQL + '

INSERT #Table3
SELECT EmployeID, PayID, Amount
FROM #TMP
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ' + STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + '(''' + ID + ''',' + ID + ')' FROM 
             #Table1 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
           ) + '
) A(PayID, Amount)
SELECT * FROM #TMP
DROP TABLE #TMP'


PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)

SELECT * FROM #table3 WHERE employeid='E001'

DROP TABLE #table1
DROP TABLE #table2
DROP TABLE #table3
```

my problem is there are 2 employee E001, E002, and three pay code.so after executing it should show one record as one employee.but it shows multiple.secondly, if add pay3 like below
('PAY2', '(PAY1+PAY3*12%)') Then it not working.

Comment: I really don't understand why you are doing a `CROSS APPLY` to insert the data. You have 2 tables, #TMP with 3 rows and #table1 with 2 rows. The `CROSS APPLY` will give you 6 rows being inserted. Correct me if I'm wrong. And also, give a little more description on what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: i have 3 table table1 payhead master and table2 employee payheadwise salary.i want to calculate as per formula column and insert into table3.for example in table 2 employeid-E001 in Pay1-2000 so for Pay2 which is formula column should calculate as per pay1 value and insert into table 3 like empid-E001,payid-pay1,amount-2000 next,Empid-E001,Payid-pay2,amount-240(calculate as 2000*12/100) NextRow-Empid-E001,Payid-pay3,Amount-2240(pay1+pay2) .so as per formula it should be calculate and insert into 3rd table.

Comment: someone pls help

Comment: Don't just reiterate your question - answer the comment - how many records do you expect to be inserting? 6? 3? 2?

Comment: i need each employee with multiple payhead.for example for  E001 it should E001--Pay1-Amount,E001-Pay2-Amount,E001-Pay3-Amount.like so other employee also.